# Rewrite URL - how to do a SEO-friendly Unicode custom URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, seo

[image: SEO vs. Unicode]
After a major load of 404 with some category and tag URL, [I questioned on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683371/how-to-transform-encoded-url-to-readable-texts) about [my WordPress blog](http://nishachor.com). My blog is in Unicode Bānglā. After a [nice anatomy on the fact in Facebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5sp1mm94giix07/Facebook%20Chat%20screenshot.jpg)<sup>1</sup> with some CodeGeeks, we came to a solution for both 404 on Unicode characters and SEO for Unicode sites.

**THE IDEA**
[Mr. Sarim Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726122/sarim) (*the Gittu*) suggested a nice solution for a URL:

- **For category:** `http://www.example.com/category/astronomy/জ্যোতির্বিজ্ঞান‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌`
- **For posts:** `http://www.example.com/%postid%/আমার-পোস্টটি-যে-বিষয়ে`

For this case the article will browse with the preceding category `/astronomy`, and will work for English SEO too. And the rest of the section `/bānglā-slug` would work for Bānglā SEO, and with this method the 404 can be minimized to a great extent.

But for a nice URL with Bānglā contents, I can manage my post and page URL, when I'm writing my page or post. But for Bānglā tags, and categories, how can I achieve such a modified URL? How can I put a Bānglā and English tag/category (taxonomy) at a time?

**REAL QUESTION**
Currently I'm following `http://domain/%postname%`. How can I rewrite my URL, so that I can achieve such a benefit of lesser 404 for Unicode URL, and also doesn't get down in SEO chase.

Desired URL is:
`http://domain/%english-slug%/%bangla-slug%`

And of course: *Is that really possible?*

<sup>1. Facebook thread image: I'm afraid, most of the discussion was in Bānglā.</sup>

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. The 404s come from broken copy & paste or dumb crawlers. There isn’t much you can do about that. Adding a trailing slash will help a little bit. If you want an English slug for a Bangla Category, just edit the slug in the category manager.

Comment: @toscho `http://www.prothom-alo.com/economy/article/55104/কোরবানির_পশুর_চামড়ার_দাম_নির্ধারণ‌` is a URL used by *The Daily Prothom Alo* - a popular Bangla Newspaper. It may be a different framework or CMS, I don't care, but it's recently done - I guess to make the site more SEO-friendly. Yes you are right I can put English slug by editing the Category/Tag, but what about posts? If I activate the `%postname%` permalink it activates a `/postname` for my post URL. How can I make it understand to put the post_id first and then with a slash my Bānglā slug. And when I'm writing a post, I'm...

Comment: ...assigning it to a category or tag and the slug creates for it automatically. How can I make the WP understand that I want a path for the category like 'take the English slug first and then put a Bānglā slug there after? I have to edit categories and tags - I don't want it that way. If I want it be done automatically, then isn't it preferred?

Comment: You can set `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/` as permalink structure. Do you want the Bangla and the English category names in the URL?

Comment: *"Do you want the Bangla and the English category names in the URL?"* - exactly that what I need. And I want it by default with a click or code-tweak.

Comment: This would require a major rewrite of the existing _add term_ metabox. Adding a slug field to the term edit pages and using that in an URL is simple. Writing a new metabox for that is rather time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your post titles in Bānglā but set the post slug in English, you can do this:

```
 function wpse117090_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post ) {
    return str_replace( '%posttitle%', sanitize_title( $post->post_title ), $permalink );
 }

 add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'wpse117090_pre_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

Then change your permalink structure to, for example, `/%postname%/%posttitle%/`

(Please note that the above code doesn't make `%posttitle%` an actual queryable rewrite tag, it's just a simple string that gets replaced by the sanitized post title when the permalinks are created.)