# What are the downsides to uploading filenames in different languages?

Tags: multi-language

I am building a Wordpress site that is going to be multilingual (using WPML) and it will host a ton of resources in multiple languages - from Chinese to Russian to English, etc. We wanted to upload the files using the native languages filename and I was going to add a filter to `sanitize_file_name` to accomplish this. After some reading, I cannot find a good explanation of why this may not be a good idea.

My question is, why would this not be a good idea? Should I avoid this? What implications would it have if I allowed all characters to be used?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `sanitize_file_name` to what? You said *to accomplish this* this - what? Uploading different language's filename, to me, is not a problem. But, for critical glyphs like Chinese, Bengali they take more char-space than English, and for large filenames, they can be trimmed to incomplete wordings. But local filenames can be a good plus point for local SEO.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I was saying that I was going to add a filter to the `sanstize_file_name` because as of now, it adds dashes in the place of spaces and specific characters like those of Chinese file names. So, are you saying that it is not necessarily a bad idea? What about for the permalinks? Would it just add `%` to the characters that it does not recognize? How would that translate?

Comment: I think for SEO `hyphen` is a very good separator and recommended. And I [questioned about this sometime](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/117090/22728). You can avoid 404 for local filenames using a permalink of `example.com/id/filename`.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I am not worried much about SEO since the site is very organizational-centric, but I do appreciate the insight. So, it looks like what I could do is keep the characters for the file names and just use English title for the permalinks with dashes as my separator, which is what I am currently doing. Thanks for your help!!!!